# Assigning different tasks to different list items

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a list item and it has 3 items in it. I want to do the following: When I clicked one of them, I am redirected to google, and when I clicked other, I go to facebook and so on. In my code, when I click any of the 3 list items, I go to same address:google. How can I assign different links for different list items? Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Listimizde kaç tane eleman olduğunu bulmak için bunu kullanıyoruz
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.linkList);

    String[] links = new String[] { "http://www.facebook.com",
            "http://www.twitter.com", "http://www.hurriyet.com.tr" };

    // ArrayAdapter, bu listviewin nasıl görüneceğini belirtir. ilk argument
    // this, yani bu list
    // 2. argument list viewin şekli, yani simple dropdown şeklinde olsun,
    // 3. argument de links
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, links);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter); // start the adapter for the list view
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos,
                long id) {
            // SO listener
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(myWebLink);
        }
    });

    // OR listener

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that over the position id

```
switch (pos){

case 1:
//go to google
break;
case 2:
//go to facebook
break;
default:
//where ever you want
break;
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you! But what is the logic behind this? is pos one of the defined variables in listview?

Comment: You are welcome. this is just an e.g.. in the reality the pos begins with 0 and correspond to the order in your listview

Comment: Thanks, just one more quick question, my list items appear at the bottom part of the page, i mean, last item is at the bottom of screen and others are built on top of it. I want the first item on top of screen and others to be placed after the first, after one another. How can i do that?

Comment: I think you have a little problem with your xml layout. Try to ask the question over stackoverflow with a little screenshot so that we can figure out your problem. Let me know as soon as you do it

Answer (score 1):

if you have a fixed order you could evaluate the `pos` parameter

```
switch (pos) {
  case 1 :  myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")); break;
  case 2 :  myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com")); break;
  case 3 :  // do something totally different
}
```

In case you can't rely on the position or you have only links (and potentialy a lot of them) you could use the AdapterView:

```
String url = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos);
myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse(url));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: no I didn't - great minds think alike ;) - it took me just a minute longer, 'cause first I started with a version almost identical than yours - then I thought of the possibility using `getItemAtPosition()`; in order to show the advantages of both solutions, I changed my example

Comment: Thanks, just one more quick question, my list items appear at the bottom part of the page, i mean, last item is at the bottom of screen and others are built on top of it. I want the first item on top of screen and others to be placed after the first, after one another. How can i do that?

Comment: That is not usual - if you have a list, items are usually aligned from the top of your ListView. How does your layout look like?

Comment: here is my layout:
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/linkList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/linkList" >

    </ListView>

Comment: thanks, here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373062/how-to-align-list-view-to-the-top-of-the-page