# How to align list view to the top of the page

Tags: android, eclipse

My list items appear at the bottom part of the page, i mean, last item is at the bottom of screen and others are built on top of it. I want the first item on top of screen and others to be placed after the first, after one another. How can i do that? 
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Listimizde kaç tane eleman olduğunu bulmak için bunu kullanıyoruz
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.linkList);

    String[] links = new String[] { "Facebook", "Ek$iSozluk", "Youtube",
            "Twitter", "Hurriyet", "Gmail" };

    // ArrayAdapter, bu listviewin nasıl görüneceğini belirtir. ilk argument
    // this, yani bu list
    // 2. argument list viewin şekli, yani simple dropdown şeklinde olsun,
    // 3. argument de links
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, links);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter); // start the adapter for the list view
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos,
                long id) {
            // SO listener
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
            switch (pos) {

            case 0:
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
                // go to google
                break;
            case 1:
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.eksisozluk.com"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
                // go to facebook
                break;
            case 2:
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
                break;
            case 3:
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.twitter.com"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
                break;
            case 4:
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.hurriyet.com.tr"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
                break;
            case 5:
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.gmail.com"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
                break;
            default:

                // where ever you want
                break;
            }

        }
    });

    // OR listener

}
```

and here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/linkList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/linkList" >

</ListView>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't align your ListView to the bottom. More specific, remove both alignment lines:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/linkList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

`alignParentTop` takes a boolean, not a reference. Also, this is standard, so you don't need it here.
`alignParentBottom` is what causes your problem, you're aligning to the bottom of the parent.

Also, `wrap_content` on a `ListView` height is generally a bad idea.